# Apply inputType a editText

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext

I need to apply an input Type a `editText` from Java. What I need is to provide the numeric keypad to enter a phone number. I can not apply the inputType in the xml layout because the editText is dynamically generated.

I tried it with:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
```

but it is not working properly, does not give me the numeric keypad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting the input type for an EditText programatically you have to specify that input class type is text like:

```
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, my code it's fine a precondition avoid passing through that part, but your information will be useful for following occasions me

Answer (score 1):

Set property in XML like this:

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/myNumber"
  android:digits="0123456789."
  android:inputType="numberDecimal"
/>
```

OR you can use:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Comment: I need to apply an input Type a editText from java. read the question

Comment: Thank your link has helped me